# Display current directory not full path

Tags: cmder

Cmder/conemu by default displays the full current path, I'd like to it to show only the current directory. Is that possible?  I've looked at the settings and have been unable to locate where or how this might be done.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew's answer worked! But I did a little tweak to make it look more legit for the language.

Open `cmder_folder/vender/clink.lua`. Right after the following code where the `cwd` is made,

```
local old_prompt = clink.prompt.value
local cwd = old_prompt:match('.*(.:[^>]*)>')
if cwd == nil then cwd = clink.get_cwd() end
```

I added the following lines inspired by Andrew's code.

```
local function get_folder_name(str)
    index = str:match'^.*()\\'
    local dir = string.sub(str, index+1)
    return dir
end    

cwd = get_folder_name(cwd)
```

And it works perfectly for me.

[image: my screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Good afternoon,
I was having this same issue myself today. I could not find an answer so I made my own solution. I will share it bellow. I have never written in lua before, so I am sure my code is not the best. However, it does work.

The prompt for cmder is being built in a LUA script. 
You are going to have to edit the cmder\vendor\clink.lua file.
around line 44 you will see a line that starts with: local cmder_prompt
That is where the prompt itself is being built.

The "{cwd}" is the bit in that line that prints the path. 
So I added a function that took that cwd variable and stripped all the values off except for the last directory in the list. So add this function to your lua script:

```
get_folder_name = function(str)
        index = str:match'^.*()\\'
        local name = string.sub(str, index+1)
        return name
end
```

then I added this just before the local cmder_prompt line where I am passing in the cwd variable:

```
dir = get_folder_name(cwd)
```

Then finally change this line from:

```
local cmder_prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg}{svn} \n\x1b[1;39;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
```

To:

```
local cmder_prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m"..dir.." {git}{hg}{svn} \n\x1b[1;39;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
```

In case it is not clear, I will paste the code that I have below. My code below makes the prompt look like this: {myUsername@mycomputerName}:directory $

```
    -- build our own prompt
    -- orig: $E[1;32;40m$P$S{git}{hg}$S$_$E[1;30;40m{lamb}$S$E[0m
    -- color codes: "\x1b[1;37;40m"
    username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
    host = os.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")

    dir = get_folder_name(cwd)
    local cmder_prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{"..username.."@"..host.."}:\x1b[1;94;40m"..dir.." \x1b[1;39;40m$ \x1b[0m"
    local lambda
    cmder_prompt = string.gsub(cmder_prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
    if env == nil then
        lambda = "λ"
    else
        lambda = "("..env..") λ"
    end
    clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(cmder_prompt, "{lamb}", lambda)
end

get_folder_name = function(str)
        index = str:match'^.*()\\'
        local name = string.sub(str, index+1)
        return name
end
```